# Xss when echoing direct from url

Tags: php, xss

I am printing directly form the url like

```
if(isset($_GET['name']){
   echo $_GET['name'])
}
```

but my friend told me that its bad and vulnerable to XSS now how is it bad and what should i do to prevent XSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap content that should not contain tags in htmlspecialchars

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
```

Comment: so you mean i should use this function everywhere when i want to echo content ..taken by user ?

Comment: Definitely a good start, but note that `htmlspecialchars` alone is not a silver bullet against XSS, especially when putting user input into HTML attributes, for example. It's all about context; what you specifically do with the user input.